# Is there a connection between the Hebrew words 'midbar' and 'dabar'?

Tags: hebrew

Midbar מִדְבָּר in the Hebrew means desert (wilderness or lonely place)(Botterweck, 8: 87 ff.). Dabar דָּבַר in Hebrew means to speak (2: 84 ff) and is a word which is theologically pregnant – it is oft used to express divine speech in the biblical text. You can see the word ‘dabar’ in the word ‘midbar’ though scholars tell us there is no etymological relationship between the two (2: 90). But taking hermeneutic liberties--poetic license if you will--it seems to me there is at least a semiotic connection if not theological. It is often in those “lonely places” that God chooses to speak to people.

We can see 'midbar' used in Genesis 27: 6 to mean speaking "And Rebekah spake unto Jacob her son, saying, Behold, I heard thy father speak unto Esau thy brother, saying"(KJV) "וְרִבְקָה֙ אָֽמְרָ֔ה אֶל־יַעֲקֹ֥ב בְּנָ֖הּ לֵאמֹ֑ר הִנֵּ֤ה שָׁמַ֨עְתִּי֙ אֶת־אָבִ֔יךָ מְדַבֵּ֛ר אֶל־עֵשָׂ֥ו אָחִ֖יךָ לֵאמֹֽר׃"

Sources

Valerie Angenot, A Companion to Ancient Egyptian Art, “Semiotics and Hermeneutics” edited by Melinda K. Hartwig (Hoboken: John Wiley & Sons, 2014), 98-118.

G. Johannes Botterweck, et. al., Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament (Grand Rapids: Wm. B. Eerdmans’s Publishing Co, 1978).

Benjamin Davidson, The Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon (Peabody: Hendrickson Publishers, 1995).

Aron Dotan et. al., Biblia Hebraica Leningradensia (Peabody: Hendrickson Publishers, 2001).

Comment: The Hebrew language by itself is not actually on-topic here - you need to ask about a specific verse from the Bible.

Comment: @curiousdannii  You are imposing a new rule. The topic is Hermeneutics which is the method by which meaning is derived from scripture.  For an example of a question with no scripture see: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/are-all-major-hermeneutical-methods-compatible?rq=1

Comment: @Bob That's a question about hermeneutical principles, not the Hebrew language.

Comment: @curiousThe answer given below is a sensus plenior answer as are so many others in SE BH. Please leave the tag.  And I will give you sources which show that meaning is derived from the Hebrew alphabet.

Comment: "Hermeneutics is the theory and methodology of interpretation, especially the interpretation of biblical texts,"  The sensus plenior methods discussed in so many other posts here demonstrate it.

Comment: @BobJones You've written an answer giving a sensus plenior, as you could for almost any question, but this question is not *about* the sensus plenior hermeneutical principle, it is about the Hebrew language, and is off-topic, as you can see by going to Close -> A community-specific reason -> Questions about biblical topics but without a specific Bible passage are off-topic as hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text is referenced.

Comment: As such I've rolled back your edit because it is inappropriate. You can't add the sensus-plenior tag to any question you want to answer with a sensus plenior, that's not how tags work. And for the record, I don't think you were even were giving a valid sensior plenior, because that concerns the deeper meaning of texts, not random words.

Comment: You can see from [this Meta discussion](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/2757) that almost all questions about the Biblical languages but not about specific texts have been closed.

Comment: @curiousdannii, please reference a tag rule for me.. In 8 years I have not seen guidance.

Comment: @BobJones That's actually a little difficult, I'm not sure there is one. Everything just says to tag what the questions are about. For this question to be tagged sensus-plenior you'd have to say that it directly implies that approach, but I really can't see it. [Wikipedia says sensus plenior concerns texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensus_plenior), which this doesn't. "Semiotic connection" is not something I think has a clear meaning, and the idea that God speaks in the "deserts" of life may be true, but would anyone really suggest that sensus plenior in passages with the word "desert".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107682/discussion-between-bob-jones-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: @David, מדבר is used as 'speaking' in these verses . Ge 27:6, Ge 29:9, Dt 4.33 , Dt 5:26, Jsh 5:14, Jdg 6:17 , 1Sa 17:23, 1Ki 1:42, 2Ki 6:33 , 2Ki 8:4, Jb 1:16, Jb 1:17, Pr 2:12, Isa 63:1, Jer 26:7, Jer 38:1, Jer 43:2, Ezk 2:8, Ezk 44:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have hit upon the metaphoric meaning of מגבר as both 'speaking' and 'wilderness'. 
The wilderness is a secondary metaphor. Like 'Waterloo', place is used for a metaphor of an activity that takes place there.

An interesting study would be to find any outliers: are there accounts of someone going to the 'wilderness' and not speaking to God in the literal or sensus plenior?

Looking at the formation of 'midbar' מדבר using Rabbi Eliezer's rule 30 [Rules of Rabbi Eliezer](http://www.betemunah.org/rules.html)

מ-דבר from מ speaking דבר, or  father מ speaking דבר

מד-בר being measured מד  the son בר

מ-ד-ב-ר the father's מ command ד revealed to man  ב as the Word ר

מ(דב)ר Bitterness (death) מר with mutterings דב or the command revealed to man ד-ב at the heart.

There are three events which are 'revelationally' related in the sensus plenior because they represent the son offering a sacrifice in the desert:

Moses was told that he would be like God to Pharaoh and Aaron would be his mouthpiece. (the word 'kiss' נשק also means 'burn').

> Ex 4:27 And the LORD said to Aaron, Go into the wilderness to meet
>   Moses. And he went, and met him in the mount of God, and kissed him.

Israel was called the son of God. They went to the wilderness to sacrifice to God.

> Ex 8:28 And Pharaoh said, I will let you go, that ye may sacrifice to
>   the LORD your God in the wilderness; only ye shall not go very far
>   away: intreat for me.

Jesus was tempted in the wilderness. He was obedient to God, and obedience is the better sacrifice.

> 1Sa 15:22...Behold, to obey [is] better than sacrifice, [and] to
>   hearken than the fat of rams.

Who did they go into the wilderness to hear? The father: 
מ-דבר from מ speaking דבר, or  father מ speaking דבר

Who was being measured?  The son:
מד-בר being measured מד  the son בר

Who was being revealed to the world as the Word? the Incarnate Torah? Jesus:
מ-ד-ב-ר the father's מ command ד revealed to man  ב as the Word ר

And what is the picture of Christ's death in the wilderness?
מ(דב)ר Bitterness (death) מר with mutterings דב or the command revealed to man ד-ב at the heart.

Aaron burned (offered himself) to Moses

Israel offered sacrifices to God, all of which are types of Christ.

Jesus was the stone that was rejected , which became the bread that we eat at communion. 
Jesus had already cast himself from the highest place in his incarnation and would descend to the lowest place in his death.

The ideas presented here are foreign to many Christians but are common to Jews.

Hebrew words derive meaning from the meaning of the letters.

1. See SMS's answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69442/whats-the-origin-of-this-approach-of-trying-to-obtain-meaning-from-the-individu
2. Sefir Yetzirah "some early commentators treated it as a treatise on mathematical and linguistic theory as opposed to Kabbalah." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Yetzirah
3. Any book on Kabbalah, which I do not endorse. What's is observable is that belief that the letters have meaning.
4. Current works by https://www.linkedin.com/in/rabbircklein/  who is attempting to coerce the meanings from the letters.
5. This is the one which I am currently testing. https://sensusplenior.net/wiki/Pneumnemonic_Hebrew_for_Beginners  using the rules posted here: [What are the strict set of rules followed by sensus plenior?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/what-are-the-strict-set-of-rules-followed-by-sensus-plenior)
6. I am currently collaborating on a Dictionary of 'Gates'; two-letter sub-roots.
7. John demonstrates a knowledge of this in 1Jo 5:7 Where heaven שמים has three consonants (yes and one vowel) which mean father מ, Word ם and Spirit א.  And earth ארץ having Spirit א, water ר, and blood ץ. Naturally he translated into Greek for the emerging Greek church which did not have a background in Hebrew.
8. Works and lectures by Rabbi Benjamin Blech https://www.rabbibenjaminblech.com/

Comment: Are you saying one word has four different etymologies? And are you saying individual Hebrew characters have whole meanings by themselves? You absolutely must provide sources to back up your argument.

Comment: @curious  Done. Thanks. It improves the article very much.

Comment: Post notice removed - thanks for including citations. Apologies, you didn't finish your tag there and we don't get any kind of automated notifications, so I've only just found this by looking through your previously flagged answers.

Comment: @Steve  Sorry. I don't know what you mean by 'finish tag'

Comment: You didn't tag curiousdannii's whole name, so it didn't send him a message to let him know you'd responded. It will ping you any time anybody writes on your content, but for everybody else it only sends them a notification if you tag them.

Comment: Thanks, I will be more careful.